# JPA data source storage location

Tags: java, jpa, datasource

I tried to search what the JPA data source storage location defaults to and how to specify a specific location but dind't find anything.

I found out that under Tomcat the database is saved inside a directory with the name of the datasource inside the bin/ of Tomcat directory which puzzles me for two reasons:

1. because the database is not an executable and should not reside inside bin/
2. because all webapps share the same bin/ directory so two datasources with the same name but of two different webapps would collide.

if I understand correctly the datasource represents the the actual JPA underlying database while the persistence units group together entitities which will be stored inside the data source. So I should be looking for properties of the data source and not of the persistence unit.

**==EDIT==**

So far I have declared a persistence unit name inside persistence.xml, I have added the configuration for this persistence unit inside META-INF/context.xml with the following

```
<Context path="/exampleWeb">
   <ResourceLink global="ds/exampleDS" name="ds/exampleDS" type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
</Context>
```

the type of database to use I think is decided based on the libraries I have, being the only one available is eclipselink-2.4.1.jar.

Inside web.xml I have:

```
  <resource-ref>
    <description>DB Connection</description>
    <res-ref-name>ds/exampleDS</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
  </resource-ref>
```

**==EDIT 2==**

Inside Tomcat's server.xml I have

```
<Resource 
auth="Container" 
driverClassName="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver" 
maxActive="20" 
maxIdle="10" 
maxWait="-1" 
name="ds/exampleDS" 
type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
url="jdbc:derby:exampleDB;create=true" 
  />
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear. Neither Tomcat nor JPA comes with a database.

You're supposed to choose which database you want to use (PostgreSQL, MySQL, Oracle, DB2, HSQLDB, etc.), install it and configure a schema (and choose, during the installation, where the data must be stored), and then configure Tomcat and/or JPA with the URL of the database.

It looks like you're using a lightweight database that stores its data in the current directory, which happens to be the `Tomcat/bin` directory because that's whare Tomcat is started from. This is a situation that is specific to your choice of database and configuration, and not a standard situation at all.

If you want help on how to configure your database with Tomcat and JPA, tell us which database you're using, and show us the current configuration.

Comment: I added my configuration details

Comment: That still doesn't show which database you're using and how it's configured. This should be defined in tomcat's server.xml file. Where did you get this configuration from? Who wrote it, and based on what?

Comment: Thank you, I found the missing configuration inside Tomcat's server.xml. I thought the persistence configuration was only inside the webapp configuration files instead it is also present inside Tomcat configuration!

Comment: @JBNizet - Could you show me some config for persistence.xml and I'm using wildfly as sever. Could you see my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39628608/how-to-use-a-database-as-your-database-source-in-jpa