# How to use a database as your database source in JPA

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, wildfly

I'm new in developing apps in JBoss so I followed their tutorials specially in making the Ticket Monster. For now, I've created an Event JPA Entity and in the run, it shows that I can save an event. But when I restart my computer, it seems the event I've saved is lost, so research about it and found some info about in-memory database. My problem is how do I tell/configure my project not to use in-memory database but to use the typical database so every time I restarted my computer the data was in the database. I would like to use PostgreSQL for my database. My current datasource profile that is set to JPA is `TestDB` but the datasource of my persistence.xml is

```
<persistence version="2.1"
   xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
        http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
   <persistence-unit name="primary">
      <!-- If you are running in a production environment, add a managed 
         data source, this example data source is just for development and testing! -->
      <!-- The datasource is deployed as WEB-INF/ticket-monster-ds.xml, you
         can find it in the source at src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/ticket-monster-ds.xml -->
      <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/ticket-monsterDS</jta-data-source>
      <properties>
         <!-- Properties for Hibernate -->
         <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
         <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
      </properties>
   </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

it said that `<jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/ticket-monsterDS</jta-data-source>` not the `TestDB`. Also, I would like not use the `create-drop` but instead a value that could tell if there is something in the database do not drop it but use it and or create if no existing.

**UPDATE**

Heres my ticket-monster-ds.xml

```
<datasources xmlns="http://www.jboss.org/ironjacamar/schema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.jboss.org/ironjacamar/schema http://docs.jboss.org/ironjacamar/schema/datasources_1_0.xsd">
    <!-- The datasource is bound into JNDI at this location. We reference 
        this in META-INF/persistence.xml -->
    <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ticket-monsterDS"
        pool-name="ticket-monster" enabled="true"
        use-java-context="true">
        <connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:ticket-monster;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1</connection-url>
        <driver>h2</driver>
        <security>
            <user-name>sa</user-name>
            <password>sa</password>
        </security>
    </datasource>
</datasources>
```

Comment: May I have a look at the code where the insertion to the database is done?

Comment: I don't know where is the insertion code because I've used JForge Tools to create an Endpoint which has EntityManager obj. But heres the create method of the EventEndpoint @POST
 @Consumes("application/json")
 public Response create(Event entity) {
  em.persist(entity);
  return Response.created(
    UriBuilder.fromResource(EventEndpoint.class)
      .path(String.valueOf(entity.getId())).build()).build();
 }

Comment: Yea, i'm referring to that(The code where `entityManager` is used).

Comment: User using an in-memory database and is surprised when at restart the "in-memory" information is not in memory any more. That's the point of in-memory

Answer (score 1):

You can continue to use the H2 database from the example.  H2 can be configured to write to a file.  You just need to change your connect string.

eg.  `<connection-url>jdbc:h2:~/test;<connection-url>`

See the [H2 documentation](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#database_url) for further options.

Comment: could I use H2 database to communicate to PostgreSQL by configuring it?

Comment: No, H2 is a SQL database just like Postgress.  You'll have to get a Postgres DB up and running and configure the jdbc connection URL to point to the running Postgres DB if that's the db you want to use.

Comment: The example I provided is a way to use H2 for your example AND have the data you persist saved between JVM or computer restarts.

Comment: ok, thanks a lot, for answering but this is not the answer I want.

Answer (score 0):

So after I posted on the jboss forum, here's the link [Wildfly 10: Cannot upload deployment](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/272452) , Wolfgang Mayer answered that I should not declared a datasource more than once. Here's the step.

1.You can set a datasource via your Admin Console(localhost:9990) or via your Project(*-ds.xml), **not both**. Please remember the JNDI(Java Naming and Directory Interface) of your Datasource.

Example:
`Datasource
Name:PostgresDS
JNDI:java:/PostgresDS
Connection URL:
jdbc:postgresql://host:port/databasename`

2.Tell your project or war to use your datasource you've created. Edit your pesistence.xml and put the JNDI of your datasource.

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1"
   xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
        http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
   <persistence-unit name="primary">
      <jta-data-source>java:/PostgresDS</jta-data-source>
      <properties>
         <!-- Properties for Hibernate -->
         <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
         <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
      </properties>
   </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

3.(Optional) If you created your datasource in Admin Console, delete your *-ds.xml file in your project folder to prevent the "Datasource is already registered" error.